Children's book about a one way street where everything goes one way
It's one of those things where I remember it extremely clearly while also not remembering useful details or being sure of my "clear" memories. But it's a children's picture book, in verse, about a one-way street, where at first it has the cars going one way, then it shows people walking only that same way, birds flying that way, etc... On this one-way street, EVERYTHING only goes one way.
And I swear each page/verse/stanza ended with a couplet where the first line ended with a word rhyming with street, and then the closing line each time would be "We [drive/walk/fly/etc] one way on this one way street." Which, you would think remembering specific language would help make it searchable, but no: I've tried every variation on that line that I can think of, and none of the search engines seem to know it.
My parents don't remember it, and neither does my brother. I asked a moderately successful children's book writer in my family about it and she had no idea. Other children's book enthusiasts I know, ditto. I went to the library where I would have gotten it from as a child (if I got it from the library - no idea) and they didn't have it or know about it, but then it's been decades.
It doesn't help that I'm not 100% sure that it was a whole book or if it was just one poem in a "Where the Sidewalk Ends"-type collection. I want to say it's its own book, because I remember-without-remembering the illustrations, each focusing on a different thing that goes one way, but that could just be my imagination.
I would have been reading it in the mid to late 1980s. My suspicion is the book is a bit older than that, but I don't really know.

Does Tale of a One-Way Street match anything you remember?

Sorry to reply so terribly late. No, that is definitely not it, but thank you!

no worries. You have a pretty good description here, I just think it overlaps too much with other stories, but I hope someone smarter than me can still find what you are looking for!
